# How to load url with "POST" type httpMethod in TTImageView?

Tags: iphone, ios, http, post

I am using `TTImageView` for loading images asynchronously in iPhone.
But the url for image is **POST** type.
How can I load url with **POST** type **HttpMethod** in `TTImageView`?
Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

TTImageView doesn't support POST method. You should load image data using a library like AFNetworking. And then do `[UIImage imageWidthData:data]` to get UIImage and provide it to the image view.

Comment: By the way, I recommend you to use SDWebImage because Three20 has moved to NimbusKit.